# is android:versionCode="1" and android:versionCode="10100" same in the android?

Tags: android

I have just came across a question about versionCode in Android I basically using ionic framework to build android app so in the config file which is responsible for creating **AndroidManifest.XML**

my older version had VersionName="0.0.1" and VersionCode="1" and in order to upload apk to playstore again I have to increase versionCode

so instead I changed it to VersionName="1.1.0" and removed VersionCode attribute and after **build** it has generated **versionCode="10100"** in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

so "1" and "10100" are same or should I set manually versionCode="2" to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: You should manually add a versionCode which is a preferred way.. Also, 1 and 10100 are both different integers where 1 < 10100. and its your choice on how to increment the version codes on every release, be it by +1 or +10 or +100

Comment: Of course 1 and 10100 are different, but ideally we should increment it by 1 on every build

Comment: yep but 1 is set manually and 10100 are generated itself and for 1.2.0 its 10200. I have checked official documentation for android versionCode but I was still confused that.

Comment: so 10100 will be accepted after 1 or should I changed it to 2 now?

Comment: You should manually add code....with proper incremental integer...so I think 2 is good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version code is integer value. It should be greater than previous version code. That's it.**

You should add version code manually in gradle file....with proper incremental integer.
So in your case I think 2 is good option and yes 1 and 10100 is of course different. :)

Comment: Yes it is integer value but for cordova(for ionic framework) it has to be string